# Is there a relation between the magnitude of two vectors and their dot product?

Tags: vectors

**a • b** = c

Is there any relation between |**a**|, |**b**| and c that allows c to be calculated in a different way?

Comment: $|a\cdot b|=|a||b|\cos\theta$, where $\theta$ is the (acute) angle between the vectors $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $a\cdot b = |a||b|\cos\theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: A slight annoyance is that there are two possible angles between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Yes but the angles are $\theta$ and $2\pi -\theta$ and we have $cos(2\pi-\theta)=cos(-\theta)=cos(\theta)$

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I missed that equation...do you know of any other ones?

Comment: @zerosofthezeta not for dot product.  There is a similar one for cross product (try looking on wikipedia if you are interested).